# PostgreSQL: Query for location of global tablespace?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space

I have been trying to make our database clients pro-active about not filling up the partition on which the database they are using resides.

As all our clients are on the same host as the database manager, it should be easy enough for user-created tablespaces; the client can look up the filesystem path for the tablespace (in spclocation), and use OS calls to check how much available space is available:

```
adb=> select * from pg_tablespace;

  spcname   | spcowner |    spclocation    |       spcacl        
------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------
 pg_default |       10 |                   | 
 pg_global  |       10 |                   | 
 adb        |  2033793 | /database/adb     | {adb=C/adb}
```

I can't see how, from the client, to get the path to where the global tablespace is stored; an empty string is returned for it in the above query.

Unfortunately, we have many legacy systems in the field using a particular database created in the global tablespace, and it would be a monumental effort to get it moved into a user-created tablespace.

Hopefully I'm just missing something really simple.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pg_default` and `pg_global` locations are "hardcoded".

`pg_default` lives in:

```
select setting||'/base' from pg_settings where name='data_directory';
```

and `pg_global` lives in:

```
select setting||'/global' from pg_settings where name='data_directory';
```

`src/backend/commands/tablespace.c` says so:

```
 * There are two tablespaces created at initdb time: pg_global (for shared
 * tables) and pg_default (for everything else).  For backwards compatibility
 * and to remain functional on platforms without symlinks, these tablespaces
 * are accessed specially: they are respectively
 *          $PGDATA/global/relfilenode
 *          $PGDATA/base/dboid/relfilenode
```

Please also note, that exposing location of data directory is a - not so terrible but still - security hole.

```
app01@postgres=> show data_directory;
ERROR:  must be superuser to examine "data_directory"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, in our installations at least, there is no matching row for name='data_directory'in pg_settings, even though the location on disk for the postgreSQL database is definitely not the default.

Comment: @Peter, the row is not visible for non-superuser account.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL creates `pg_default` and `pg_global` when you create a cluster, perhaps by using `initdb` directly. The `initdb` utility can take an argument that sets the data directory, but no arguments about where to put the `pg_default` and `pg_global tablespaces`.

I'd conclude they're always created in the data directory. I could easily be wrong about that. I don't think they can be moved. I could be wrong about that, too.

But if I'm right up to this point, you can derive their physical location by

```
show data_directory;
```

The `pg_global tablespace` is almost certainly is the "global" subdirectory; `pg_default` probably is, too.

If I had time, I'd read [the source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/). That would remove all doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, (as I said to filiprem), in our installations at least, we don't seem to have the data_directory available via settings lookup (as superuser), even though the location on disk for the postgreSQL database is definitely not the default (we're using 8.3.11-1).

Comment: Don't forget if postgres spins  inside a docker - so the path is not on your host!